# How to remove surrounding code block in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ IDEA, is there shortcut to remove surrounding code block (control structure) around selection in a context aware manner? In this example, I would like to remove the outer if block.

Transform this

```
if (foo) { // Unnecessary if block

  a();

  if (bar) {
    b();
  } else {
    c();
  }
} else {
  d();
}
```

to this

```
a();

if (bar) {
  b();
} else {
  c();
}
```

Comment: If you change it to `if(true)`, will IntelliJ detect that the code serves no purpose and give you the option to remove it?

Comment: Otherwise, put two slashes  next to the ending brace, delete the opening `if`, and then delete the ending brace.  There should be some option in IntelliJ to fix the brace indentation; in Visual Studio, you can do it by simply removing the last closing brace and putting it back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `Code | Unwrap/Remove` action (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on Windows). It will popup a list where you can select which surrounding structure you want to remove.

Comment: Anyone knows if vscode supports this?